# How much is the dimension of some bidirectional LSTM layers?

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, lstm, seq2seq

I read a paper about machine translation, and it uses projection layer. Its encoder has 6 bidirectional LSTM layers. If input embedding dimension is 512, how much will be the dimension of the encoder output? 512*2**5?

The paper's link: https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/P18-1008.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Not quite. Unfortunately, Figure 1 in the mentioned paper is a bit misleading. It is not that the six encoding layers are in parallel, as it might be understood from the figure, but rather that these layers are *successive*, meaning that the hidden state/output from the previous layer is used in the subsequent layer as an input.

This, and the fact that the input (embedding) dimension is *NOT* the output dimension of the LSTM layer (in fact, it is `2 * hidden_size`) change your output dimension to exactly that: `2 * hidden_size`, before it is put into the final projection layer, which again is changing the dimension depending on your specifications.

It is not quite clear to me what the description of *add* does in the layer, but if you look at a [reference implementation](https://github.com/zomux/nmtlab/blob/master/nmtlab/models/rnmt_plus.py#L77) it seems to be irrelevant to the answer. Specifically, observe how the encoding function is basically

```py
def encode(...):
    encode_inputs = self.embed(...)
    for l in num_layers:
        prev_input = encode_inputs

        encode_inputs = self.nth_layer(...)
        # ...
```

Obviously, there is a bit more happening here, but this illustrates the basic functional block of the network.

Comment: Thanks! Reference implementation is really helpful for me.

Comment: If this is answering your question, please consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer to mark this question as "Done".